# problem with this string comparing method

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

The following method needs to return the name of the person who has the first last name at the dictionary. in case of same last names the method will compare between the first names on the persons and determine which of those has the first name according to the dictionary.
for example : 
the given names : "dan","coco","rocky". the name "coco" will be returned because "c" is before "d" in the dictionary.
the method is:

```
 public String firstPerson()
    {
        String   lastName=_persons[0].getLastName();
        String firstName=_persons[0].getFirstName();
        String answer=_persons[0].getFirstName();
        for(int i=0;i<_numOfPersons;i++)
        {
            if((_persons[i].getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(lastName))>0)
            {
                lastName=_persons[i].getLastName();
                answer=_persons[i].getFirstName();
            }
            else if((_persons[i].getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(lastName))==0)
            {
                if((_persons[i].getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(firstName))>0)
                answer=_persons[i].getFirstName();
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

I think this is the solution but for some reason the method returns me always the last person in the array and not the one's I need.

Comment: Change `>0` to `<0`.

Comment: To put it in another way `getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(lastName)) > 0` means in this context: Update `lastName` if the last name of the person is lexicographically after `lastName`. This means that always the lexicographically last name will be the result, you want the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you're attempting to find the minimal value by a compound comparator. Instead of implementing this yourself, just let Java's streams and comparators do the heavy lifting for you:

```
public String firstPerson() {
    return Arrays.stream(persons)
                 .min(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName, 
                                           String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
                                .thenComparing(Person::getFirstName, 
                                               String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
                 .orElse(null);
}
```